# Capitalize First Character after space of a String If complete sentence is uppercase java

Tags: java

I have some problem, how to capitalize the first word of a String if all the sentence is an uppercase.
For example : "VESSEL ONE (L) INC"
The output that I want : "Vessel One (L) Inc"

Currently, I apply this code, but this only works if all the sentence in lower case

```
String source = "vessel two management sdn bhd";
StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
 for (String str : strArr) {
  char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
  stringArray[1] = Character.toLowerCase(stringArray[1]);
  str = new String(stringArray);

  res.append(str).append(" ");
  }

res.toString().trim()
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please prefer `StringBuilder` over `StringBuffer`. Second, you might use [`WordUtils.capitalizeFully(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29) like

```
String source = "VESSEL ONE (L) INC";
String capitalized = WordUtils.capitalizeFully(source);
```

or (if you can't use apache commons) you could write your own like

```
private static String capitalizeFully(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean cnl = true; // <-- capitalize next letter.
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (cnl && Character.isLetter(c)) {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
            cnl = false;
        } else {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
        }
        if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            cnl = true;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "VESSEL ONE (L) INC";
    System.out.println(capitalizeFully(source));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html), if using lib. is an option.

The other way might be to convert whole string `toLowerCase` before applying the operation you specified above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b.+?\\b").matcher(source);
    while(m.find()) {
        String s = m.group().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + m.group().substring(1).toLowerCase();
        m.appendReplacement(sb, s);
    }
    String res = sb.toString();
```